# visual studio 2017 cordova ios debug in local device failed

Tags: ios, cordova, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-cordova, apache-cordova

This is link of the same problem I raised in Visual Studio Developer support portal.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/61875/visual-studio-2017-cordova-ios-debug-on-local-devi.html

I am trying to debug cordova app in iPhone 5s local device connected to my laptop.

```
visual studio 2017 cordova 7.0.1 xcode 8.3.1 ios 10.2.1
```

**After build it is failing at deployment.**

build successful but failing to deploy to IOS device.

it is bringing up itunes and then shows the app there and device is identified but says error occured continue or not? and fails.

Earlier I deployed and several times debugged directly with local device.

one error result states, version mismatch other says device may not be connected and awake.

I am using ipod 9.3 version ios and another one iphone 5s with 10.2.1 ios.

I am building apache cordova app in visual studio 2017 with macincloud remotebuild.

how to resolve this!? any hint is a big help!!

I am manually deploying but can't debug. now, 
**i am getting network error at xmlhttprequest in device and but same code working fine in simulator.**

when press device button then and i restart app then it is dumping a big error message and showing exitapp though i am not using any of that plugin or code line.

how to debug on device is first priority which may help to resolve rest.

```
1>Time Elapsed 00:05:02.04 2>------ Deploy started: Project: BlankCordovaApp2, Configuration: Debug iOS ------ 2>Found iTunes version: 12.3.2.35 2>Uninstalling app ID: COM.appanem.appanem. 2>Successfully installed .ipa file: C:\Users\Ekambarrao\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\BlankCordovaApp2\BlankCordovaApp2\bin\iOS\Debug\appanem.ipa. 2>Starting idevicedebugserverproxy.exe at port 3000. 2>Cannot find the app installed on the device. Check that the device is connected, awake, and unlocked. 2>Starting ios_webkit_debug_proxy.exe at port 9221. 2>Deployment failed.
```

Is everybody happily working with this latest releases of Cordova IOS xcode vs 2017 or everybody facing the same problem as I am?

Comment: I have not received any reply in this regard or at least a comment. Am I the only one facing this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Issue is resolved, I am able to debug after I built my own VM of IOS and then debug but not sure what really resolved this.

What I can make out is,

unlike earlier, (not sure correct or wrong because this I could not do when I was using macincloud),

now the provisional profile need to be tagged to even device for debugging which was earlier sufficient to just list the device uuid in store certificates and profiles section.